# Mibian returning "NameError: name 'norm' is not defined..." when using with xlwings

Tags: python-3.7, xlwings, mibian

I was trying to write an Excel UDF using xlwings to return finance options calculation from the Mibian library. I've tried the code below.

```
import xlwings as xw
import mibian

@xw.func
def BSPutOptionImpVol(underlyingPrice,strike,interestRate,expiryDays,premium):
    c = mibian.BS([underlyingPrice, strike, interestRate, expiryDays], putPrice=premium)
    return c.impliedVolatility
```

From Excel, I then call the function with the following `=BSPutOptionImpVol(45,32,1,127,0.95)`

It's returning the following error:

> "NameError: name 'norm' is not defined
>       call = self.underlyingPrice * norm.cdf(self.*d1*) - \
>     File ""C:\Users...\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\mibian__init__.py"", line 307, in _price
>       [self.callPrice, self.putPrice] = self._price()
>     File ""C:\Users...\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\mibian__init__.py"", line 276, in **init**
>       estimate = eval(className)(args, volatility=mid, performance=True).putPrice
>     File ""C:\Users...\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\mibian__init__.py"", line 29, in impliedVolatility
>       self.**class**.**name**, args, putPrice=self.putPrice)
>     File ""C:\Users...\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\mibian__init__.py"", line 293, in **init**
>       c = mibian.BS([underlyingPrice, strike, interestRate, expiryDays], putPrice=premium)
>     File ""c:\users...\documents\python scripts\BSPutImVol.py"", line 6, in BSPutOptionImpVol
>       ret = func(*args)
>     File ""C:\Users...\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\xlwings\udfs.py"", line 298, in call_udf
>       res = call_udf(script, fname, args, this_workbook, FromVariant(caller))
>     File ""C:\Users...\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\xlwings\server.py"", line 195, in CallUDF
>       return func(*args)
>     File ""C:\Users...\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\win32com\server\policy.py"", line 586, in _invokeex_
>       return S_OK, -1, self._invokeex_(dispid, lcid, wFlags, args, None, None)
>     File ""C:\Users...\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\win32com\server\policy.py"", line 283, in _invoke_
>       return self._invoke_(dispid, lcid, wFlags, args)
>     File ""C:\Users...\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\win32com\server\policy.py"", line 278, in _Invoke_"*

I have also tried just calling the function without passing the parameters in (ie the input values are in the python code) but I still get the same error.

However, if I comment out xlwings and just run the Python code from Spyder as below, it works.

```
#import xlwings as xw
import mibian

#@xw.func
def BSPutOptionImpVol(underlyingPrice,strike,interestRate,expiryDays,premium):
    c = mibian.BS([underlyingPrice, strike, interestRate, expiryDays], putPrice=premium)
 #   return c.impliedVolatility
    print(c.impliedVolatility)
```

I'm a newbie to Python, so appreciate any help and advice. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Try..

```
from scipy.stats import norm
```

Comment: Add a text to your code where it will explain

Answer (score 0):

Try add

```
import scipy
```

to your code. That resolved the 'norm' issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

```
pip uninstall numpy scipy
```

and then

```
pip install -U numpy scipy
```